# Why does an archive expire?

Tags: plot-explanation, archive

In the Sci-fi movie, ***Archive***, when a person dies, this person's body (consciousness) is stored into a large digital box so that other living people can still talk to this dead person.

What I do not understand is:

- Why does this consciousness expire?

Given the size of this archive box, I am not really sure whether the physical body is stored in there or not. I guess if the body is stored in there, there will be a point in time that it slowly decays.

[image]